# How to add support for HTML5 notifications in XAML Webview in a UWP app?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webview, uwp

So I am using a `WebView` in my UWP application and I would like to handle [HTML5 notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/windows-integration/web-notifications-api). What I did was to add support for the `ScriptNotify` event to my webview ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify)).

```
 MyWebView.ScriptNotify += WebView_Notify;
 private void WebView_Notify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("NOTIFIED " + e.Value);
 }
```

Then using `InvokeScriptAsync`I ran the following javascript code:

```
(function() {
    var N = window.Notification;

    window.external.notify(N.permission);
    var P = function (title, options){
        window.external.notify(title)
    };
    P.permission = 'granted';
    N = P
})();
```

However, this does not work. In my debug output I do get:

> "NOTIFIED default`

which means that `ScriptNotify` handler is being triggered. However, how can implement HTML5 Notifications support in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a new solution that might help you.

A notification request is initiated when the page loads, WebView can intercept it, using the event `PermissionRequested`.

```cs
private void WebView_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PermissionRequest.PermissionType == WebViewPermissionType.WebNotifications)
    {
        args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
    }
}
```

You can also pop up a window when you listen for a request, letting the user choose whether to accept the notification.

Best regards.

Comment: This seems great! However, I found 2 main issues: first one is that upon restart the `WebView` doesn't "remember" that the permission has been granted previously and second is that I am not sure how to intercept when a notification is triggered.

Comment: Regarding the first point. Yes, every time you restart WebView, it is equivalent to creating a new browser, it will not save and record user data. Regarding the second point, unfortunately, I have not found a way to externally intercept the triggered notification and get the content.

Comment: yes, first problem can easily be solved but I am still looking for a solution for the second problem. See my attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523910/intercept-html5-web-notifications-in-a-browser-environment)

Comment: @daljit97 can you outline how you solved the first problem?